# VIM: search urls

Tags: url, search, vim

I found a nice search pattern to find all emails in a text in VIM:
`\([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]\+\.[a-zA-Z]\{2,4}\)`

Does anyone has a nice search command to find all url's in VIM?

Comment: Since searches in VIM are based on regular expressions, this page might be a useful resource: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it - `\(\(ht\|f\)tp:\/\/\.*\)\s`

Comment: Thanks, what would be your code if I want to match all text after http/ftp except `"` and except `\s` ?

Comment: Hi, this is supposed to match the entire URL. You should change the regex to match only the text after (ht|f)tp):// till \s